# Configuring bulk Msol users with non-English Values

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to configure a bulk of Msol users via .csv file with non-English values.
First tried importing the values I want to set from the .csv file and didn't get any error and the user I tried to update didn't get updated.
Then, I tried setting the account by writing the non-English values in Powershell and got an error that mentions my non-English values. 
Is there any special syntax for non-English values? something in my code were I tried to import the values from the file is the problem?

Thanks.

The code:

`Import-Csv C:\Documents\Changes.csv | Get-MsolUser | Where {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq $_.userprincipalname} | Set-MsolUser -Department $-.class -Office $_.school -Title $_.title`

The Error:

Set-MsolUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '××œ×™××'. At C:\UserChanges1.ps1:5 char:143 + ... ipalname} | Set-MsolUser -Department "×ž×•×¨×”" -Office "××œ×™×× ×¡ ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUse

Comment: "got an error" - what error? (Remember, respondents here can't see your screen.)

Comment: Can you explain your definition of non-English values? UTF8 instead of ASCII?

Comment: Sure, got the error below, and by non-English values I refer to Hebrew for example
Set-MsolUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '××œ×™××'.
At C:\UserChanges1.ps1:5 char:143
+ ... ipalname} | Set-MsolUser -Department "×ž×•×¨×”" -Office "××œ×™×× ×¡ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUser

Comment: Go ahead and update your question with your error message (use 4 spaces to indent to indicate a code block), rather than posting it as a comment.